# How to log Django CronJob function errors to the console?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, cron, django-cron

I have a CronJob function in Django, parsing and saving data. The huge problem is that if something is wrong, no logs appear in console in terminal, which makes life and debugging very difficult. How to log to console in development mode on localhost?

```
class ParseFromKarabasCron(CronJobBase):
     RUN_EVERY_MINS = 1 # every 2 hours

     schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
     code = 'app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

     def do(self):
         pass
```

http://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

From this comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38861/where-is-the-cron-log-file-in-macosx-lion#comment44006_38865

"According to , you could modify the cron plist (/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.vix.cron.plist) with a Stdout/Stderr path to debug cron itself. I don't recall if launchctl unloading and launchctl loading the plist is sufficient, or since it's a system daemon if you'd have to restart entirely. I'd suggest the latter just to be sure."

The erikslab.com link shows how to add these to the .plist

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/progname.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/progname_err.log</string>
```

Comment: All other errors normally go to console, it's all right except job function. OS X

Comment: I edited my answer. The linked answer should help you.

Comment: sorry, I just opened the file and see just some small html-like structure, and I can't really get where to add

Comment: Added more complete info. Sorry it took a few days. Let me know if this is still unclear.